# React Hook Form, Yup - Array of objects with checkbox - Only one should be checked

Tags: react-hook-form, yup

Im beginner in yup, I have a scenario as below

I'm using useFieldArray to build the form.
User can add multiple contacts using append and can remove using remove functions in useFieldArray.

The requirement is if a person adds multiple contacts, at-least and max one contact should be primary check box checked

```
**Schema:**

yup.object().shape({
      contacts: yup.array().of(
        yup.object().shape({
          contact_name: yup.string().required('Contact name required'),
          title: yup.string(),
          phone: yup.string(),
          email: yup.string().required('Email is required').email('Please enter valid email'),
          isPrimary: yup.boolean()
        })
      )
    })
```

Please guide me with right solution.